# Properties .yml in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a connection to a database to read data. Now every time I go up to production or develop I must manually change a line in my class

```
// config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/asterisk");
// config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://185.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/asterisk");
```

I want to add it to my yaml files of development and production to automate it

And I do the following, in my yaml file I add it:

```
spring:
   ...
   datasource:
   ...
      asterisk:
        jdbc: jdbc:mysql://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/asterisk
```

And in my configuration class the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.abalia.elser2.repository_asterisk" })
public class DatabaseAsteriskConfiguration {

private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
private static HikariDataSource ds;
private static String jdbc;

static {
    // config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/asterisk");
    // config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://185.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/asterisk");
    config.setJdbcUrl(jdbc);
    config.setUsername("xxxx");
    config.setPassword("xxxx");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
}

public DatabaseAsteriskConfiguration(@Value("${spring.datasources.asterisk.jdbc") String jdbc) {
    DatabaseAsteriskConfiguration.jdbc = jdbc;
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return ds.getConnection();
}

}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.abalia.elser2.config.DatabaseAsteriskConfiguration
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call some configuration from application.yaml 
you make sure that is the same configuration key. I've take a look and the keys are different and it's missing close a bracket. 
On your application.yaml

```
spring:
   ...
   datasource:
   ...
      asterisk:
        jdbc: jdbc:mysql://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/asterisk
```

on your method call **spring.datasource.asterisk.jdbc** and close brackets.

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.asterisk.jdbc}")
```

Comment: I have closed them, but still giving the same error.

Comment: OK, could you please share your a small project related with your issue? so that  I can help you.